# Is a character literal ('A') exactly equivalent to a hex literal (0x41)

Tags: c, hex, character, literals

Is there any situation in which changing `'A'` to `0x41` could change the behaviour of my program? How about changing `0x41` to `'A'`? Are there any uncommon architectures or obscure compiler settings or weird macros that might make those to be not exactly equivalent? If they are exactly equivalent in a standards compliant compiler, has anyone come across a buggy or non-standard compiler where they are not the same?

Comment: Yes. Any [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) platform will *not* be compatible with this change. The most well-known examples include IBM AS/400 and IBM OS/390

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Is this the only place the change will be incompatible? Or might there be others?

Comment: Not getting into the signed/unsigned 'char' debate, you're potentially swapping a `char` type with something "not `char`". That in itself could have unintended consequence. As answers below point out, the value difference is just one issue. The standard itself specifically calls out the implementation-dependent nature of character sets.

Comment: @Drew There *could* be others, but as far as I know, there aren't.

Comment: @WhozCraig Character literals have type `int`.

Comment: @Zack and hex constants likewise? Learned something new. Thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig The precise (C99) rule is, an unsuffixed hexadecimal or octal constant is the narrowest signed or unsigned type no smaller than `int` which can represent the value; a decimal constant, however, is always signed.  `int` is required to be able to represent at least the range [-32767, 32767], so any unsuffixed integer constant -- regardless of base -- small enough to fit in either `signed char` or `unsigned char` (whose minimum ranges are [-127, 127] and [0, 255] respectively) is representable as `int` and will thus have that type.

Comment: Oh, also, this is one of the places where C++ is not a superset of C.  In C++, a single-character unprefixed character constant has type `char`.  (This is to make overloaded function calls less surprising.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Is there any situation in which changing 'A' to 0x41 could change the behaviour of my program?*

Yes, in EBCDIC character set `'A'` value is not `0x41` but `0xC1`.

C does not require ASCII character set.

> (C99, 5.2.1p1) "The values of the members of the execution character set
>           are implementation-defined."

Answer (score 3):

Both the character literal `'A'` and the integer literal `0x41` have type `int`.  Therefore, the only situation where they are not exactly the same is when the basic execution character set is not ASCII-based, in which case `'A'` *may* have some other value.  The only non-ASCII basic execution character set you are ever likely to encounter is [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), in which `'A' == 0xC1`.

The C standard does guarantee that, whatever their actual values might be, the character literals `'0'` through `'9'` will be consecutive and in increasing numerical order, i.e. if `i` is an integer between 0 and 9 inclusive, `'0' + i` will be the character for the decimal representation of that integer.  `'A'` through `'Z'` and `'a'` through `'z'` are required to be in increasing alphabetical order, but *not* to be consecutive, and indeed they are not consecutive in EBCDIC.  (The standardese was tailored precisely to permit both ASCII and EBCDIC as-is.)  You can get away with coding hexadecimal digits A through F with `'A' + i` (or `'a' + i`), because those *are* consecutive in both ASCII and EBCDIC, but it *is* technically something you are getting away with rather than something guaranteed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd *want* to get away with that, since that means needing to handle 0-9 and A-F separately anyway - `"0123456789ABCDEF"[i]` seems both simpler *and* character-set agnostic.

Comment: @caf For symmetry with the next function over which *decodes* hex numbers, maybe?  I think "getting away with" this is actually useful when you're going in the other direction, it saves you a potentially-huge lookup table.  (Which you may have anyway, of course.)